# Selenium webdriver is not working in Safari browser 5.1 in Windows 7

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

I am trying to run Selenium Java Code in SAFARI browser in windows 7 ,  it throws "TimeOutException" as shown below,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out awaiting response to command "findElement" after 30003 ms (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

The following are the system requirements used:

- Safari browser 5.1
- selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar
- selenium-safari-driver-2.43.1.jar
- SafariDriver.safariextz
- Windows 7 64-bit
- Jdk 1.8

The application consists of login page with userid and password textboxes.

The above exception is thrown in the login page.

the following is the selenium java code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.safari.noinstall", "true"); 
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get("baseUrl");  
driver.findElement(By.name("userid")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("userid")).sendKeys("hello");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123456");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnSubmit")).click();   
driver.close();
```

The following is the jsp code :

```
<input type="text" name="userid" value="" maxlength="128" size="9">
<input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="46" size="20" autocomplete="off">
```

The same code works fine with CHROME browser. It is not working in SAFARI browser.

Waiting for answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible issues here are: Safari is unsupported on Windows and virtually nobody uses it; big discrepancy between driver and server version; old driver version; possibly mismatched extension version... https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver

Comment: Also, is "baseUrl" really your URL?

Comment: I have changed driver version to selenium-safari-driver-2.53.jar , still same issue exists..

Comment: "baseUrl" is string which contains the original URL. that is not a problem.